# Default data format (localization)

Tags: reportbuilder3.0

I wondered if anyone knew of a way to have the default localization set to en-GB (UK dates, rather than US dates). The scenario is this;

1. I open report builder 3
2. Set up a datasource and data set in the query designer, if I return a date column it is in the UK dateformat.
3. However when I drag columns on to a table and then run the report the dates are in a US format.

To correct this I have to then edit my localisation for the column or I can do it for the whole report to be en-gb and this works.

However is there a way to have it default to en-gb so I don't need to do this modification with each report. Firstly I thought it was using my PC localisation settings but these are UK, then I wondered if there was something I could set in the Report Builder manifest or alike?

Thanks,

Nic

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to actually be an issue with the language pack installed in IE on the Report Server.

Everything was set to a UK locale however the language option in IE wanted to download the UK language pack.

By installing it and then selecting the UK language pack in IE for the SSRS service account this resolved the issue.

Thanks for your assistance,

Nic